# MVVM Inheritance following SOLID principles

Tags: solid, wpf, mvvm

I'm currently at the design phase of my program (hence no code).
It will be written in WPF in C# using MVVM principles.

I'm going to have a multifunctional Drag & Drop control, that will act similairly to a Facebook's Post on the Wall.

To make this clear, imagine it could be a calendar event, an important note, a product update etc.

That means they will differ in models that they will be based on.

What do you think would be the most SOLID approach to building such a control?
What I came up with:

1. Have a single control object, that based on the "type" that it is created as, inherits different models. (though I'm not entirely sure how I will manage to do that yet.
2. Have different controls for each "type" that all inherit from a base control class and extend the basic functionality.
3. Any other solution, that could be even better?

Comment: `Have different controls for each "type" that all inherit from a base control class and extend the basic functionality.` -- This is the usual approach.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to follow the maxim "favor composition over inheritance." In other words instead of baking in behavior at compile time, wire it up at runtime. This follows the "Open/Closed Principle" of SOLID, which states that code should be open to extension, but closed to modification. In other words, you should strive to design your code in a manner that you can extend its behavior (with abilities like drag-and-drop) without having to modify the existing source code (by modifying the base class to add drag-and-drop).

IoC containers are useful for "wiring objects up" at runtime without having to change any code.

Comment: UI hierarchies are typically an exception to the "favor composition over inheritance" rule.  They don't require the flexibility that composition provides in a business logic context.